# Parse the ul tag and form an array based on li tag data

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML as shown below

```
<div class="t1t2Wrapper" style="padding:0px 10px 0px">
   <ul class="breadcrumb pull-left" id="mybreadcumb" style="background:none; margin-bottom:0px;">
      <li>PQR<i class="icon-angle-right"></i></li>
      <li>Burger<i></i></li>
   </ul>
   <label class="pull-right" style="padding:8px;"><label>Brand Name</label>None</label>
</div>

var ids = [];
    $('.breadcrumb').each(function () {
        ids.push($(this).find('li').text());
    })

    alert(ids);
```

How to create an Array as

PQR,Burger

http://jsfiddle.net/6kb7dhwq/2/

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the `li` tags as well as the `ul` tags...

http://jsfiddle.net/6kb7dhwq/5/

```
var ids = [];
$('.breadcrumb li').each(function () {
    ids.push($(this).text());
})

alert(ids);
```

What you were previously doing just got all the text from the child `li` tags, concatenated.  This treats them as individual elements and therefore pushes each bit of text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the children, not the UL:

```
var ids = [];
$('.breadcrumb').children('li').each(function () {

    ids.push($(this).text());
})

alert(ids);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6kb7dhwq/4/

Answer (score 1):

In you selector, if you had used `'.breadcrumb > li'` or `'.breadcrumb li'` instead of `'.breadcrumb'` your code would have worked fine. However, I would like to share another way to do it.

You can use `.map` as follows:

```
var ids = $('.breadcrumb > li').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

```js
    var ids = $('.breadcrumb > li').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

alert( ids )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="t1t2Wrapper" style="padding:0px 10px 0px">
   <ul class="breadcrumb pull-left" id="mybreadcumb" style="background:none; margin-bottom:0px;">
      <li>PQR<i class="icon-angle-right"></i></li>
      <li>Burger<i></i></li>
   </ul>
   <label class="pull-right" style="padding:8px;"><label>Brand Name</label>None</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6kb7dhwq/7/

```
var ids = [];
$('.breadcrumb li').each(function () {        
   ids.push($(this).text());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the li items instead of the ul, and then iterate over each li with the .each() function. Example below:

```
$('.breadcrumb li').each(function () {
    ids.push($(this).text());
})
```